# Strange screen on Nexus 4

Tags: android

I have this strange glitch on my Nexus4 screen when testing a very simple layout: just a linear layout with a TextView inside. Does anyone have an idea why and how to fix this bug ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/highlighted_text_material_light"
    android:id="@+id/measurement_tv"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

This happens systematically when I use a simple layout but there is no problem for a more complicated layout
[image: Screen glitch]

Comment: Are you 5.0? Super buggy if so! Nexus 4 has 5.1 OTA out so update if this is the case.

Comment: Upgrading to 5.1 doesn't solve the problem :(. Maybe it is hardware issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a possible cause, but it is not programming related:

Is it possible that You have enabled HW Overlay. Sometimes it conflicts with rendering the layout. To disable or enable, go to:

> settings-->developer options-->deactivate HW-Overlays

Had a similar problem, my screen looked like Yours and this was the cause.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled the HW-Overlays but the problem persists :(

Comment: than try to change other GPU rendering options....I´m pretty sure it is not programming related....

Comment: I just try disabling/enabling "Force CPU Rendering" and "Disable HQ overlays" but the screen is always glitched ...